# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/thrift/TEnum

Tags: java, jdbc, jar, cql

I have tried with the following code to connect CASSANDRA Database on my local system.

Here is my code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DBConnect {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

Connection con = null;
try {
Class.forName("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9160/mykeyspace");

   String query = "select * from users";

   Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
   ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(query);

   while (result.next()) {
    System.out.println(result.getString("user_id"));
    System.out.println(result.getString("fname"));
    System.out.println(result.getString("lname"));
   }

  } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (SQLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  } finally {
   if (con != null) {
    try {
     con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    con = null;
   }
  }

 }}
```

and here is a error message which i recieve.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/thrift/TEnum
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.Utils.<clinit>(Utils.java:62)
at org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver.connect(CassandraDriver.java:85)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at DBConnect.main(DBConnect.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.thrift.TEnum
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 17 more
```

I have added following Jar files.

1. apache-cassandra-thrift-1.2.5.jar
2. cassandra-jdbc-1.2.5.jar
3. slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
4. slf4j-jdk14-1.7.5.jar

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `apache-cassandra-thrift` depends on `libthrift` artifact. You need to add this jar in your classpath. You can find it [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.thrift/libthrift).